# How to find total size and available size of an USB connected to Android device in latest android version

Tags: android, usb, size

I'm trying to find out the capacity of USB device connected directly to Android device and also SD Card connected via card reader (not direct insertion to phone).

I tried various methods to find out the size of the USB, but in vain. (Already tried StatFs, ContextCompat, etc. - all these not listing USB).

Is there any direct way to get the size? I don't want to use DocumentTree as i don't want user to manually select volume and give permission.

I see few filemanagers are able to get the size values when USB is connected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `I don't want to use DocumentTree as i don't want user to manually select volume and give permission.` So you are telling us that if you did you could determine sizes? Please show the code.

Comment: I remember doing something similar long back. i don't have code right now.. is there any other way to get USB sizes?

Comment: Well i'm quite interested in that code.